# regex preg_match PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need some help with a regular expression.  I am trying to match user agent strings for mobile css.  Right now, I am having trouble matching mobile but not iPad.  In other words if I had two user agent strings that looked something like,

```
random stuff ipad random text in between mobile
```

and

```
random stuff iphone random text in between mobile
```

The way I have it setup is something like,

```
if (!preg_match("/(?!ipad).*mobile|iphone|blackberry/",$user_agent)
{ // show desktop version 
}
else { //show mobile version 
}
```

however I am not even sure if that is right, and I am not getting the desired result I want.  Again the end goal being to show the desktop version on ipad.

Comment: I highly recommend taking a look at https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect - makes this much easier!

Comment: Agreed, my head is spinning right now.  More so because of the double negatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!preg_match("/(!ipad|iphone|blackbary).*mobile/",$user_agent)
{ // show desktop version 
}
else { //show mobile version 
}
```